# I can't retrieve boolean data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an Android chat application. At this context, I am trying to let people add friend each other(a classic). But I can't retrieve boolean data from Firebase Database. It is always returning false/maybe null. Check my Firebase backend;

```
friends{
 552nQquUrtSgbVVLgXxfxOh6SL52{
      NuJohj7nalWnpiMfC1zl3r77QDt2: true
      vIYkKWAWwKTRD4NQfixzcNnfk6X2: true
   }
}
```

And my Android code is below;

```
 public boolean checkFriend(final String uID){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("friends");
    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           ret= (Boolean) snapshot.child(uID).getValue();               
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("HATA OLUŞTU!","FriendManager checkFriend'de veri tabanı bağlantısı hatası oluştu."+ databaseError);
        }
    });
    Log.i("Database", mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).toString()+" +++ "+uID+" ++++ "+ ret.toString());
    return ret;
}
```

And my logcat is below

```
05-17 03:40:35.803 22488-22488/com.furkan.profil I/Database: https://profil-95859.firebaseio.com/friends/552nQquUrtSgbVVLgXxfxOh6SL52 +++ 539vt6Cwi0Y4dF3qmgI6LN1kJJo1 ++++ false
05-17 03:40:35.805 22488-22488/com.furkan.profil I/Database: https://profil-95859.firebaseio.com/friends/552nQquUrtSgbVVLgXxfxOh6SL52 +++ NuJohj7nalWnpiMfC1zl3r77QDt2 ++++ false
05-17 03:40:35.805 22488-22488/com.furkan.profil I/Database: https://profil-95859.firebaseio.com/friends/552nQquUrtSgbVVLgXxfxOh6SL52 +++ vIYkKWAWwKTRD4NQfixzcNnfk6X2 ++++ false
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return ret` will run before `onDataChange`. `return ret` don't wait until `onDataChange()` or `onCancelled()` finished because they run in different thread

```
mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // this will run in different thread 
        ret = (Boolean) snapshot.child(uID).getValue(); // the value that from Firebase is here
    }
});
// this will run before onDataChange
return ret;
```

So you need to change your funtion to

```
public void checkFriendThenDoSomeThing(final String uID){
    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           ret= (Boolean) snapshot.child(uID).getValue(); 

           // DO SOMETHING after get ret from Firebase
        }
        ...
    });
}
```

**======**
**OR If you want call** `checkFriend(...)` from another `Activity`, your need to:
First, declare a interface for `Listener`

```
public interface CheckFriendSuccessListener {
    void onSuccess(boolean value);
}
```

Put the `Listener` to your function like

```
public void checkFriend(final String uID, CheckFriendSuccessListener onCheckFriendSuccessListener){
    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean ret= (Boolean) snapshot.child(uID).getValue();
            onCheckFriendSuccessListener.onSuccess(ret);
        }
    });
}
```

then when you call the checkFriend

```
checkFriend("someUserID", new CheckFriendSuccessListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(boolean value) {
         // DO SOMETHING after check friend successful
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand your point. I declared `boolean ret=false` at top. That's why I was thinking, I am retrieveing false data. But I am calling this function from other activity. I've to return some data to it.

Comment: @FurkanÖyken I have update my answer, please check it

Comment: I checked it. Also added   `if(snapshot.hasChild(uID))` at onDataChanged(). Otherwise it was returning null. But I solved it now. Thank you for your help. Thanks to you I just learned interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the `ret` inside the `onDataChange` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    ret= (Boolean) snapshot.child(uID).getValue();
    Log.i("Database", mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).toString()+" +++ "+uID+" ++++ "+ ret.toString());
    doStuff(ret); // user ret here
}
```

Comment: onDataChange is a void function. When I am trying to do that it will give me an error obviously.

Comment: @FurkanÖyken Ohh.. you're right. Then you should call another function with that `ret` for example: `verifyFriend(uID, ret);` then that function can do what you originally intended to do.